# What Perl code should I include when I ship the product?

Tags: perl, product

When shipping a product to customers what code should I include?

```
 use strict;
 use warnings 'FATAL';
```

.etc

Comment: It is *very* dangerous making any assumptions about a deployment environment you don't control. Starting with what versions of Perl will this work with, you need to test this in all contexts you expect/hope it will work in, and then create a script to verify you have the necessary tools installed.

Comment: In theory, if your stuff was properly developed, you wouldn't need them enabled in the production version of code.

Comment: @Peter use v5.8.0 should work.

Comment: @bitbucket: Ok, but what about 5.14.1 (current)? And what about modules and their versions? Any dependencies on system services, tools, pathnames, or APIs? I'm not trying to give you a hard time, but you may be in for a rude shock about how different various flavors of U*NX, Linux, etc. can be, even systems that you *think* should be identical twins.

Comment: @Peter thanks, I'm still testing.  Fortunately, I only need to support Gnu/Linux and for version 1.0 only Debian and Redhat platforms.

Comment: @bitbucket: Good, that narrows it down. Depending on what you are doing, though, there are still a few differences between RH and Debian. One thought occurred to me: if you are doing any sort of network stuff with other machines make sure you specify which ports you need opened. Debugging unseen, remote firewall problems is a *huge* PITA. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to work with your customer to determine the minimum version of Perl that will be installed on the platform.

Then place a `use 5.010;` for the right version at the top of your code.

If your code compiles and runs properly under `strict` and `warnings`, then there is no reason to remove them.  It is a good thing if the script then breaks on deployment, because it lets you know about some bug that did not crop up during the testing phase.

You may want to implement a logging solution so that rather than bailing out, a proper log is created that the customer can then send to you for diagnosis.

You can also package up your product as a CPAN module to take advantage of the dependency testing and resolution.